# remove joomla facebook and twitter link plugin

Tags: joomla3.0

i am using joomla and I want to remove the four link tabs that reffers to googleplus twitter and facebook and news feeds . they are on top of the home page  . how can I do that .

Answer (score 0):

Those are added by your template. Check your template's configuration (from your backend), it most likely will have an option for you to disable it. If not, check your template's files (located in /templates/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked my plugins but I could not find anything useful . I am using the pronostar template . it has no useful option to remove this . I have found my template files but I do not know wich file I should change.

Answer (score 0):

1) It could be a module. Then you should go to `Extensions > Module Manager` under *Administrative Panel* and turn off the module with *Social icons*. It could be named arbitrarily, but you could find it by position.

For Joomla 3, [positions are drawn here](http://bj.zemplate.com/protostar-responsive-template/protostar-module-positions).

2) It could be configured in the template. Then, go to `Extensions > Templates > Styles > Protostar` and open it by clicking the template name.

I have the following settings with my (other) template:
[image: social buttons settings]]